# How to hide a window in Windows 7, just like desktop managers do

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7

When I install a virtual desktop manager on Windows 7, and I switch to a different virtual desktop, all the current windows disappear, also disappearing from the Start Menu.

I want to hide some of a particular application's windows, but not all of them, in a similar manner. How can I hide a window like this?

In particular, I need to hide a VirtualBox Seamless mode window, so I'm not sure minimizing the window will work. It does, however, disappear when using virtual desktop managers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simply `ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)` and `ShowWindow(SW_SHOW)`. I think "Virtual Desktop Managers" just hide windows and show them as necessary when the desktops change.

Answer (score 1):

The same window cannot appear on multiple desktops. If you need your application window to appear on multiple desktops you need to create a separate window for each desktop. The desktop a window appears on depends on the thread that creates the window. You can change the desktop thread assignment using the SetThreadDesktop function.

Comment: I don't need the window to appear on multiple desktops. I just want one window to disappear from my current Desktop. I think that's the function I want, though... can you give me any tips on creating my own desktops?

Comment: The CreateDesktop function creates a desktop. The ShowWindow function can be used to change the visibility of a particular window. Both are documented in the MSDN Library. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library

Comment: Virtual desktop software doesn't have anything to do with the USER32 "Desktop" objects, frequently it just offsets window rectangles to put them off-screen.

Comment: Heh apparently all I wanted is ShowWindow with a `SW_HIDE` flag. but say i did want to hide it in the current desktop and display it in another one. That would be (pseudo-code): `ShowWindow(SW_HIDE); SetThreadDesktop(CreateDesktop())); ShowWindow(SW_SHOW)`? and it'll show up in the new desktop?

Comment: No, a window cannot change desktops. The desktop it is created on is the desktop it stays on. You can of course communicate with a window from a thread associated with a different desktop but that won’t affect the window’s desktop assignment.